# Comparison of definite integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Consider the integrals

$I_1 = \int\limits_0^1 e^{-x} \cos^2 x\ dx$

$I_2 = \int\limits_0^1 e^{-x^2} \cos^2 x\ dx$

$I_3 = \int\limits_0^1 e^{-x^2}\ dx$

$I_4 = \int\limits_0^1 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\ dx$

Place these integrals in descending order.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please add your question, or make it clearer. Also, have you tried anything?

Comment: I need the greatest of these integrals I.

Comment: Try to include in your post anything you have tried to provide some context.

Comment: Who upvoted this problem-statement question?

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Note that for all $x\in (0,1)$, we have that
$$e^{-x} \cos^2 x< e^{-x^2} \cos^2 x < e^{-x^2}< e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}.$$
From the left, the first inequality  holds because $\cos^2 x> 0$ and $x^2< x$, the second one because $\cos^2 x< 1$, and the third one because $x^2> x^2/2$.

Then recall that the integral is monotone: if $f(x)> g(x)$ for all $x\in (a,b)$ then $$\int_a^b f(x)dx> \int_a^b g(x)dx.$$
Here it is NOT necessary to evaluate the integrals.

Comment: How am I finding the greatest of these integrals? Can you show me the whole process?

Comment: But $\cos^2(0)=1$

Comment: @Garmekain The strict inequalities hold in the open interval $(0,1)$

Comment: Didnt notice that.

Answer (score 2):

Just perform the integrations to find:

$$I_4 > I_3 > I_2 > I_1$$

Or note the ordering at each value of $x$:

[image]

Comment: It is a bit hard to perform the integration $I_2$...

Comment: @RobertZ : Bah.  It's $\frac{\sqrt{\pi } (2 \mathrm{e} \; \text{erf}(1)+\text{erf}(1+\mathrm{i})- \; \text{erf}(-1+\mathrm{i}))}{8 \mathrm{e}}$, as anyone (with a sufficiently powerful symbolic integrator) can plainly see.

Comment: @RobertZ:  Or double bah:  ...as anyone (with a very modestly powerful *numerical* integrator) can plainly see.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork What can I say...You are right. Sometimes I make very stupid comments!